# Trying to suspend with lxqt-leave gives dbus error

Tags: linux, dbus, systemctl

I am using `xmonad` as my window manager with `lxqt-session`. When I try to suspend with `lxqt-leave` I get a notification of a DBus error that a suspend is already in progress. Here is my `journalctl -b --grep='suspend'`:

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-04-27 16:40:14 EDT, end at Mon 2020-06-01 11:09:05 EDT. --
May 29 17:51:44 Centaur lxqt-leave[8134]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 29 19:38:06 Centaur lxqt-powermanagement[1084]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 29 19:38:07 Centaur systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 29 19:38:07 Centaur systemd-sleep[18285]: Suspending system...
May 29 19:38:07 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
May 29 21:14:19 Centaur kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
May 29 21:14:19 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend exit
May 29 21:14:26 Centaur systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.
May 29 21:14:26 Centaur systemd[1]: Finished Suspend.
May 29 21:14:26 Centaur audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 29 21:14:26 Centaur audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 29 21:14:26 Centaur systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
May 29 21:14:26 Centaur kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1590801266.530:1271): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 29 21:14:26 Centaur kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1590801266.530:1272): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 29 21:14:26 Centaur systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
May 30 00:37:30 Centaur lxqt-powermanagement[1084]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 30 00:37:30 Centaur systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 30 00:37:31 Centaur systemd-sleep[35383]: Suspending system...
May 30 00:37:31 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend exit
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1590847382.283:3117): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-source-USB Audio] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-sink-HDMI 0] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur systemd[1]: Failed to start Suspend.
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Suspend.
May 30 10:03:02 Centaur systemd[1]: suspend.target: Job suspend.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 30 12:27:45 Centaur lxqt-powermanagement[1084]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 30 12:27:45 Centaur systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 30 12:27:46 Centaur systemd-sleep[51003]: Suspending system...
May 30 12:27:46 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
May 30 13:29:23 Centaur lxqt-leave[57298]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 30 13:29:24 Centaur lxqt-leave[57298]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend exit
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1590867210.290:5157): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-source-USB Audio] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-sink-HDMI 0] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur systemd[1]: Failed to start Suspend.
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Suspend.
May 30 15:33:30 Centaur systemd[1]: suspend.target: Job suspend.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 30 18:21:38 Centaur lxqt-leave[77257]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 30 18:21:41 Centaur lxqt-leave[77257]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 30 18:21:41 Centaur systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 30 18:21:42 Centaur systemd-sleep[77287]: Suspending system...
May 30 18:21:42 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend exit
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1590966695.903:6619): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-sink-HDMI 0] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-source-USB Audio] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur systemd[1]: Failed to start Suspend.
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Suspend.
May 31 19:11:35 Centaur systemd[1]: suspend.target: Job suspend.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 31 19:20:45 Centaur lxqt-leave[78546]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 31 19:20:47 Centaur lxqt-leave[78546]: QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.login1" path "/org/freedesktop/login1" interface "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member "CanSuspend": Marshalling failed: Variant containing QVariant::Invalid passed in arguments
May 31 19:20:47 Centaur systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 31 19:20:48 Centaur systemd-sleep[78575]: Suspending system...
May 31 19:20:48 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-source-USB Audio] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur pulseaudio[1223]: W: [alsa-sink-HDMI 0] alsa-util.c: Could not recover alsa device from SUSPENDED state, trying to restart PCM
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur kernel: PM: suspend exit
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur systemd[1]: Failed to start Suspend.
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Suspend.
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur systemd[1]: suspend.target: Job suspend.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jun 01 10:55:18 Centaur kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1591023318.303:6764): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-suspend comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jun 01 10:56:32 Centaur sudo[79431]:    qusai : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/qusai ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b --grep=suspend
Jun 01 11:08:37 Centaur sudo[80557]:    qusai : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/qusai ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b --grep=suspend
Jun 01 11:09:00 Centaur sudo[80589]:    qusai : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/qusai ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b --grep=suspend
Jun 01 11:09:05 Centaur sudo[80661]:    qusai : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/qusai ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b --grep=suspend
```

Only when I kill the `systemctl-sleep suspend` command started by root (I'm unsure how this was executed) does it continue to go to sleep.